# php login script doesn't redirect

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I've wrote a script that reads user and password data correctly, to log into a reserved webpage. The problem is that when you press the login button, it doesn't redirect to the target.php (reserved) page. The form is in a file called login.php.
It reads and connect to the db, but stays on this login page:

```
<?php


session_start();


function loginform(){

    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
          Username: <input type = 'text' name='username'>
          Password: <input type = 'text' name='password'>
          <input type = 'submit' name='login' value='Login'>
          </form>

    ";
}

function logoutform(){

    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
          <input type = 'submit' name='logout' value='Logout'>
          </form>

    ";

}

function login($username, $password){

    $pass = md5($password);

    $con= mysqli(whateverwebsite.com, 'Nameofthetable', 'hashedmd5password') or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('whateverdb', $con) or die (mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass' ") or die (mysql_error);

    $count= mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1) {
        $_SESSION['login']=$username;
        header('Location:target.php'); /* this does not work */
    }

    else {
        header('Location:index.php');   /* this does not work */
        echo "Wrong login";
    }

}

function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo "You've logged in";
    logoutform();
}

else{
    echo "Enter with Username and password.";
    loginform();
}

if ($_POST['login']) {
    echo "logging in..."; /* this text "logging in" remains on the screen, instead of going to target.php */

    login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}

elseif($_POST['logout']){
    echo "Logging out";
    logout();
}

?>
```

also, Before the html of the target.php page, there is this

```
<?php

 session_start();
 echo "Reserved area<br>";

 if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    exit("you must login <a href='../login.php'>Login<a>");
 }
 else {
    echo "Do the <a href='../login.php'>Logout</a>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting...

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit vague - what exactly happens?

Comment: Try to remove echo "logging in", because if header () works it will not display

Comment: try echo before     header('Location:target.php');   and say ... result

Comment: I've tried all answers. None works. Plus, putting a ahref link to target.php inside if($_POST['login']) function, causes the page to ask me the login again, causing an infinte loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this always worked for me :
This modification is in your `login` function . If it works , you can modify `else` part in similar manner .

```
if( $count == 1 )
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;

    echo
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your website title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=target.php">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Logging in . Please wait ...
    </body>
</html>';

}
```

Comment: It works if I embed the html code after the if ($_POST['login']) function. It doesn't redirect but it's a solution.

Comment: `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP . Your `echo "logging in...";` is going against this . Try removing it and your code should work .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header() function to send a new HTTP header, but this must be sent to the browser before any HTML or text (so before the  declaration, for example).

alternative:

```
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);

    exit();
}

Redirect('http://www.google.com/', false);
```

**UPDATE:**
if this does not worked use this:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php' />";
```

instead of using header

Comment: Sorry, Mehdi, I can't figure how this apply to my code. Shall I write a new redirect function?

Comment: The code behaves exactly as before, Mehdi. So the problem is not there.

Comment: Same problem. I'm starting to think the solution is not in the redirect itself but in another part of the program. I'm new to this so I recap how I did the system. There's a login(login.php) page that connects to a db, it reads user and password and grants access to target.php. It works, if after the login I manually type in the url  whateverwebsite.com/target.php. It just does not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `header()` you shouldn't echo anything.

So, check the `$_POST['login']` first, and **don't use echo** before `login()`

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='page.php';</script>";
    //or
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=page.php' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

//TRY this here

```
 if($count==1) {
        $_SESSION['login']=$username;
        header('Location:target.php'); /* this will work now*/
        //TRY
         exit(); 
    }
```

**Note : mysql_* deprecated use mysqli_  your code is highly vulnerable**

**a logic Flaw** - your code is highly vulnerable

```
  $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND    password='$pass' ") or die (mysql_error);
  $count= mysql_num_rows($result);
```

let `$username="A%"`  like some thing  its easy to have    $count>1 and logged in this

Answer (score 0):

I think this function may be the culprit. It doesn't display anything, why it doesn't get called?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo "You've logged in";
    logoutform();
}
```